# why when i start program not work but in netbeans work?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

hello when i Run my program in net beans is work but when i build this and run in cmd
(java -jar name.jar) i have this error -> http://scr.hu/1det/p8tow
i use maven this is my pom.xml->>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.gmail.desk1123</groupId>
    <artifactId>channelbot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>TeamSpeak-3-Java-API-mvn-repo</id>
            <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheHolyWaffle/TeamSpeak-3-Java-API/mvn-repo/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.gmail.desk1123.channelbot.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.theholywaffle</groupId>
            <artifactId>teamspeak3-api</artifactId>
            <version>[1.0.0,2.0.0)</version>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>
    <name>channelbot</name>
</project>
```

but when i make project without maven and add library it does not work and I got the same error

Comment: When you run your jar file, are all the dependency jar files in a `lib` subfolder of the folder where your jar file is?

Comment: yea -> http://scr.hu/1det/49oec
 and in lib i have this library;/

Comment: Open your jar file using WinZip (or similar tool), and check the manifest file. Verify that the classpath lists all the dependencies needed. Then verify that one of those dependencies actually contains a `com/github/theholywaffle/teamspeak3/api/wrapper/Client.class` file.

Comment: but what file i should have?
I have META-INF folder with pom.xml and my package with class?

Comment: Your `channelboot-1.0.jar` file has a manifest file in the META-INF folder. If it didn't, you would have seen a different error. It's a text file, so view it and check the classpath listed in there.

Answer (score 0):

I second Andreas' comment.

IDEs, or Maven plugins for IDEs, nicely maintain the classpath for you in the background. Here's the content of the `.classpath` file of a Maven project in Eclipse, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

If you're working outside of your IDE you have to take care of your dependencies yourself.